# How to pass the value of ranges to my variable call?

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, datepicker

Hello I'm using http://www.daterangepicker.com/ but in my case, I need to pass the string instead of dates.

the default `let dateDates` is: `let dateDates = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ',' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

but instead of getting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/?date_range=2021-01-26,2021-01-27`

I need it like this. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/?date_range=Today`

because on my Django-REST API. it only accepts that way on `date_range` parameter. If there is an alternative please suggest. Thank you!

```
 let dateDates = `If I choose Today, I will get 'Today' not moment() values.`;
 let defaultUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/?date_range=${dateDates}`;
 updateValueForUrl(defaultUrl);
 $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Today': ['Today'],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    }
```

Comment: _"Today"_ is not a range o.O

Comment: yea i edited it, its for the example. please read the description o.O